# SharePoint collapsible sections search function with PnP search

Tags: search, sharepoint

I have created an FAQ section on Modern SharePoint and I want to be able to search it and find the correct FAQ and expand it.

Is there a query that can be run in PnP search settings that will find the right collapsible section?

When I do a search on a page that has these sections it just returns the page as a result rather than the actual section.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the out of the box Microsoft search FAQ option in the Search and Intelligence admin center? Even if your generic search center is build using PnP Modern Search Web parts you will be able to surface the results from MS search.